# Broadcast receiver does not receive sms in android?

Tags: android

I am using broadcast receiver in my app to read OTP sent from server, I did not mention any permission in manifest.xml, but it does not read OTP  . I don't know where the problem is. Can someone help me to rectify it?Please help me.

```
public BroadcastReceiver br = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        try {
            if (bundle != null) {
                Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                assert pdusObj != null;
                for (Object aPdusObj : pdusObj) {
                    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation") SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) aPdusObj);
                    String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                    String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();

                    Log.e(s_szTAG, "Received SMS: " + message + ", Sender: " + phoneNumber);

                    // checking sms sender address....
                    if (phoneNumber.toLowerCase().contains("+919971599909".toLowerCase())) {
                        // verification code from sms
                        m_szOtpCode = getVerificationCode(message);
                        assert m_szOtpCode != null;
                        String input = m_szOtpCode.trim();

                        Log.e(s_szTAG, "OTP received: " + m_szOtpCode);
                        COTPVerificationDataStorage.getInstance().setM_szOtp(input);// getting otp from SMS and set to otpverificationstorage class

                    } else {
                        return;
                    }

                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(s_szTAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("JavaDoc")
    private String getVerificationCode(String message) {
        String code;
        int index = message.indexOf(":");

        if (index != -1) {
            int start = index + 2;
            int length = 6;
            code = message.substring(start, start + length);
            return code;
        }
        COTPVerificationDataStorage.getInstance().setM_szOtp(m_szOtpCode);
        return null;
    }
};
private IntentFilter inf;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    m_Main = inflater.inflate(R.layout.otp_auto_verified, container, false);

    inf = new IntentFilter();
    inf.addAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");


    getUserDetails();// getuser deatails....
    init();// initialize controls...
    return m_Main;

}
```

Comment: create on receiver class.. put this code inside the class and register it in manifest..

Comment: you are not registering the receiver br.

Comment: why ? Then how to register

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read `SMS` through `BroadReciever` either you could register `YourReciever` in manifest or in `YourActivity` . otherwise you cant listen broadcasts.

permission needed

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
```

static registration

```
<receiver android:name=".YourSmsReciever">
    <intent-filter android:priority="99999">
        <action android:name="android.provider.telephony.SMS_RECIEVED"></action>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

dynamic registration

```
           class YourActivity extends Activity{
    //all remaining life cycle methods will goes here

                 YourReciever yourReciever = new YourReciever;
                 public void onResume(params){
                    IntentFilter mIntentFilter = new IntentFilter();
                    mIntentFilter.addAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
                    registerReceiver(yourReceiver, mIntentFilter);
                 }
                 public void onPause(params){
                    unRregisterReceiver(yourReceiver);
                 }
            }
```

Comment: I am registering receiver in onCreate whats the problem in that

Comment: if you don't unRegister then it will cause problems. onPause & onResume are preferable places to overcome those problems. you could use onCreate and onDestroy also.

Comment: if I register broadcast receiver dynamically the I how can I make permission in menifest

Comment: in both cases <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" /> permission is mandatory.

Comment: if you are using fragments use  onCreateView & onDestroyView to register & unRegister

Comment: i am doing like that : in fragment oncreate:getContext().registerReceiver(br,inf);

Comment: @Override
 public void onDestroy() {
  super.onDestroy();
  getContext().unregisterReceiver(br);
 }

Answer (score 0):

try registering the receiver

```
public class ReceiverSMS extends BroadcastReceiver {

   // your onReceive code
}
```

and in manifest..

```
    <receiver android:name=".ReceiverSMS">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to register you broadcast receiver like below and declare necessary permissions in manifest

```
        IntentFilter mIntentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    mIntentFilter.addAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
    // mIntentFilter.setPriority(2147483647);
    registerReceiver(optReceiver, mIntentFilter);
```